# Weighted Load Balancing Algorithm into PHP Application

Tags: php, algorithm, factory, internal-load-balancer

I want to resolve weighted an Adapter from an factory which could be configured by user (enable/disable and weight %).

Example:

- AdapterW ≃ 20% of transaction
- AdapterX ≃ 30% of transaction
- AdapterY ≃ 40% of transaction
- AdapterZ ≃ 10% of transaction

I can grant that all items will never sum more than one hundred (100%), but sometimes any adapter could be deactivated.

I have the following parameters:

```
public function handleAdapter()
{
    $isWActive = (boolean)$this->_config[self::W];
    $isXActive = (boolean)$this->_config[self::X];
    $isYActive = (boolean)$this->_config[self::Y];
    $isZActive = (boolean)$this->_config[self::Z];
    $WPercentage = (int)$this->_config[self::LOAD_BALANCE_W];
    $XPercentage = (int)$this->_config[self::LOAD_BALANCE_X];
    $YPercentage = (int)$this->_config[self::LOAD_BALANCE_Y];
    $ZPercentage = (int)$this->_config[self::LOAD_BALANCE_Z];
    .
    .
    .
    return (self::W | self::X | self::Y | self::Z); 
}
```

How can i balance weighted between this adapters dynamically?

**Edit**

created a gist to a executable code: https://gist.github.com/markomafs/5d892d06d6670909f9b4

Comment: This will help you make a question that gets effective answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry, but according to this link, my question is Minimal, Complete and Verifiable. Can you help me and send a edit suggestion?

Comment: I just checked the link.  According to it, a Complete example is one such that has "all parts needed to reproduce the problem."  An MCE is something I can _run_.  I can't run your function as is.  It doesn't even have the <?php ?> tags.  When I provide it <?php ?> tags and load it, I get the error that "public" is unexpected here.  To run it, I have to fix the tags, create your object, set up some code that calls this function, and print the results. Don't know how.  Why not tell us?

Comment: MCE its about to reproduce, not exactly run and jsfiddle is about JS/HTML/CSS  not php. 

but i create a which you could reproduce : https://gist.github.com/markomafs/5d892d06d6670909f9b4

Comment: OK, I ran it.  It produced a lot of W's.  I have no way of knowing if this is correct output. So I'll give up.

Comment: the expeted output is fews "W", Some "X", More Some "Y" and many "Z"

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the best approach, but you can try something like this:

```
public function handleAdapter()
{
    //an array to return the balanced entries
    $balancedEntries[] = false;

    //verifies which of the options are active
    $isWActive = (boolean)$this->_config[self::W];
    $isXActive = (boolean)$this->_config[self::X];
    $isYActive = (boolean)$this->_config[self::Y];
    $isZActive = (boolean)$this->_config[self::Z];

    //get configured percentage of each
    $WPercentage = (int)$this->_config[self::LOAD_BALANCE_W];
    $XPercentage = (int)$this->_config[self::LOAD_BALANCE_X];
    $YPercentage = (int)$this->_config[self::LOAD_BALANCE_Y];
    $ZPercentage = (int)$this->_config[self::LOAD_BALANCE_Z];

    //here you fill the array according to the proportion defined by the percentages
    if ($isWActive) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $WPercentage; $i++) {
                $balancedEntries[] = self::W;
            }
        }

        if ($isXActive) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $XPercentage; $i++) {
                $balancedEntries[] = self::X;
            }
        }

        if ($isYActive) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $YPercentage; $i++) {
                $balancedEntries[] = self::Y;
            }
        }

        if ($isZActive) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $ZPercentage; $i++) {
                $balancedEntries[] = self::Z;
            }
        }

        return $balancedEntries;
}
```

And then, in case you want a proportion of 1 to 100 (as in percentages):

```
$balancedResult = $balancedEntries[array_rand($balancedEntries, 1)];
```

Since array_rand will return 1 key from the original array, you use it to get it's value.

Answer (score 1):

Another try, this should work for your case - But it only work if you have an adapter as a single char string, this is not visible by your question.

```
public function handleAdapter()
{
    # a map with all adapters
    $map = array(
        self::W => self::LOAD_BALANCE_W,
        self::X => self::LOAD_BALANCE_X,
        self::Y => self::LOAD_BALANCE_Y,
        self::Z => self::LOAD_BALANCE_Z
    );
    # generate a string map with one char per percentage point
    $stringMap = "";
    foreach($map as $key => $value){
        # skip if disabled
        if(!$this->_config[$key]) continue;
        # repeat the key for each percentage point
        $stringMap .= str_repeat($key, (int)$this->_config[$value]);
    }
    # return a random string char from the map
    return $stringMap[rand(0, strlen($stringMap) - 1)];
}
```

Comment: In your solution , if the adapter name has more than 1 letter , it will not work

Comment: Sorry! The adapter could have more than one letter!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I've misunderstood the question, the answer is wrong.

I understand your question so that you always want to return the adapter with the lowest load to force traffic to this adapter.

```
public function handleAdapter()
{
    $isWActive = (boolean)$this->_config[self::W];
    $isXActive = (boolean)$this->_config[self::X];
    $isYActive = (boolean)$this->_config[self::Y];
    $isZActive = (boolean)$this->_config[self::Z];
    $WPercentage = (int)$this->_config[self::LOAD_BALANCE_W];
    $XPercentage = (int)$this->_config[self::LOAD_BALANCE_X];
    $YPercentage = (int)$this->_config[self::LOAD_BALANCE_Y];
    $ZPercentage = (int)$this->_config[self::LOAD_BALANCE_Z];

    $map = array();
    if($isWActive) $map[self::W] = $WPercentage;
    if($isXActive) $map[self::X] = $XPercentage;
    if($isYActive) $map[self::Y] = $YPercentage;
    if($isZActive) $map[self::Z] = $ZPercentage;

    asort($map);
    return key($map);    
}
```

Edit: Fixed wrong `sort()`, you need `asort()` to maintain the index.

Comment: with asort, it will only response the higher Adapter percentage. 

i Wish for example:  AdapterY ≃ 40% of transaction , 40 of 100 requests will use this adapter, if you understand what i meaning.

Comment: A ok, you set the percentage of load manually and want to balance it based on this percentages. Than i am totally wrong with my answer :)

Comment: I confess, you answer was the first think I've tried.

Comment: do you have another idea?

Comment: @Markomafs Added another answer